# Why am I getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined? (Retrieving lat lng from json)

Tags: javascript, json, geocode

I want to add the lat and lng to jsonarr and write it to output.json, but something seems to be going wrong. Can someone help me point it out?

```
var jsonarr = []

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){

  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + 
dataset[0]._id + '+Netherlands&key=**')
  .then(function (response) {

    var contentlat = (response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
    var contentlon = (response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
   console.log(dataset[0]._id)
    var json = {lat: "", lon: ""};
    json.lat = contentlat;
    json.lon = contentlon;

    jsonarr.push(json)
    console.log(contentlat);
    console.log("Ewa" + dataset[i]._id);
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(jsonarr), function(err){
      // console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
    })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

 }


res.send('Check your console!')
});
```

Comment: In your code `response.data.results[0]` seems to be null. Maybe you should check if you receive `response.data.results` before, but, anyway, print response to see what you are getting.

Comment: The api-key was expired.